# Which characters and format can we use for specifying a delimiter for Hive table?

Tags: hive, delimiter

I am working on importing data from Mysql to Hive using Sqoop.

However, I am facing some problems regarding the delimiters. Actually, I know that I will be able to solve my problem by using the right delimiter for my Hive table, so it will read well the files I feed to it.

But, I searched a few hours and still cannot find any documentation on which characters I could use as a field delimiter?!

Could you please help me in finding exactly what kind of characters I can use as a field delimiter? and which format/encoding to use for specifying it?

In the official Hive documentation on confluence, I can only find that:

```
    row_format
  : DELIMITED [FIELDS TERMINATED BY char [ESCAPED BY char]] [COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY char]
        [MAP KEYS TERMINATED BY char] [LINES TERMINATED BY char]
        [NULL DEFINED AS char]   -- (Note: Available in Hive 0.13 and later)
  | SERDE serde_name [WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (property_name=property_value, property_name=property_value, ...)]
```

But, what does the "char" represent?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A single ASCII-7 character. Will not work with `¤` (that's an UTF-8 char, not a base ASCII char) nor `#EOF#\n` (multiple chars). You may use special control chars when using **octal** notation e.g. `\013` will mean Ascii 11 or `VT`

Comment: You may want to use OpenCsvSerde instead of the default Hive TEXT SerDe, it's more versatile (but slower, and does not support the same options)

Answer (score 0):

**[FIELDS TERMINATED BY char [ESCAPED BY char]]**
In this char means **any character**. Most commonly used is **comma (,)** as in CSV file (comma separated files)

However I am not able to understand, if you are sqooping Data from MySQL why do you care about Field Separator?

Either create a table in **ORC format** and sqoop the data into it. Or you can create table while importing data as well.

```
mysql_connection="jdbc:mysql://server/db_name"

sqoop import \
--connect $mysql_connection \
--username=mysql_username \
--password=mysql_password \
--table batch_control_execution \
--hcatalog-database temp \
--hcatalog-table mysql_batch_control \
-m 1
```

Add Following option to **create table**

```
--create-hcatalog-table
```

And Add following option to **specify Format.**

```
--hcatalog-storage-stanza \
'stored as orc tblproperties ("orc.compress"="SNAPPY")'
```

Comment: Thanks for your time! Could you please specify more precisely the point around that: "Could you please help me in finding exactly what kind of characters I can use as a field delimiter? and which format/encoding to use for specifying it?"

Comment: you don't need any delimeter to sqoop import data.